# Zero flux along lines

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

I am considering the $L^1$ ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and a conservative vector field $V$ on it, which arises as the gradient of a bounded, almost-everywhere Lipchitz-function. Denoting by $e_i$ as the i’th standard basis vector and $H_i$ as the hyperplane orthogonal to $e_i$, I know that $\int_{H_i} \langle V(x),e_i\rangle dx =0$ for all $i$.

My ultimate goal (potentially using other properties/assumptions) is to show the vector field must be zero almost everywhere. However, I’m having trouble concluding anything sufficiently informative about $V$. For instance, I can’t show that $V$ has divergence equal to zero (though I can for instance conclude the integrated divergence over certain regions is zero, including the whole domain). Does anyone have insight as to whether this is enough information to conclude the function vanishes? If not, does anyone know any properties this function must satisfy that I might be missing?

Comment: why would a constant vector field have zero flux through a surface?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say that the vector field is identically zero. Edited

Comment: isn't $d=2$, $V={{x_2}\choose{x_1}}$ a counterexample?

Comment: You’re right, I totally missed that! Thanks.